# Linq Group by a field and count distinct by another

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a datatable and I want to use LINQ to get the equivalent of

```
Select barid, count(distinct bar) as barCount
From myTable
Group By barid
```

The data is in the form:

```
barid bar
4     1
4     1
4     1
12    2
12    2
12    2
12    3
13    1
13    2
13    3
```

The result should be:

```
barid, barCount
4      1
12     2
13     3
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your `DataTable` columns to be of type `Integer`, you can use below query:-

```
Dim result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("barid")) _
               .[Select](Function(x) New With { _
                   Key .barid = x.Key, _
                   Key .barCount = x.[Select](Function(z) z.Field(Of Integer)("bar")) _
                                    .Distinct().Count()})
```

Then you can simply use the `ForEach` like this:-

```
For Each x In result
      Console.WriteLine("barid {0}",x.barid)
      Console.WriteLine("barCount {0}", x.barCount)
      Console.WriteLine("---------------")
Next
```

This is giving me the following output:-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I cannot translate it into vb.net but the c# equivalent would be:

```
var result = from record in data 
             group record by record.barid into grp
             select new
             {
                barid = grp.Key,
                barCount = grp.Select( item => item.bar ).Distinct( ).Count( )
             };
```

Comment: This answer is also correct, but the accepted is more complete.